# Computer That Is Member Of A Domain Can't See Domain Groups

Tags: windows, active-directory

So, I have joined to my workplace local domain. I logged in a couple of times using my domain user but now the computer won't be able to see any users or groups from the domain. Actually in the objects "Search" dialog box I can only select the current computer as "Location" to search from.

Curious thing is that the computer properties says that the machine is actually part of the domain.

Any thoughts on this matter?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Apparently I am able to ping the DC. Even though I can't list users by using the NET USERS /domain command at the command prompt. It fails with error 1355 - The specified domain either does not exists or could not be contacted.

Comment: possibly a permissions thing?

Comment: Don't think so. I used to be able to lookup for users.

Comment: Is your DNS using the same DNS as your domain controllers?

Comment: No. DCs are aver a VPN.

Comment: This likely won't work. See my answer

Answer (score 11):

Your PC/Server has to be able to find the DCs and to do so needs to share the same DNS as the DCs.  Active Directory is VERY sensitive to DNS and all clients and domain controllers need to point to a common DNS or it just won't work. In my experience, almost EVERY AD issue is due to an underlying DNS issue.

Answer (score 2):

The Computer Browser service must be running in order to view computers on the domain.  You can check to see if this is running in the Services snap-in.  Many organizations disable this service via Group Policy to comply with security requirements (so you may not have the option to turn it on).

Comment: Apparently the service is started.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you describe is likely to be resolved by simply leaving the donain and rejoining it:

1. In `sysdm.cpl`, leave the domain and join WORKGROUP.
2. Reboot.
3. Log into the domain controller, open Administrative Tools -> Active Directory Users and Computers, and verify that this machine's computer account has been deleted. (Right click on the domain, choose Find, change the type of search from Users/Groups to Computers, and search for the name of the workstation that you have removed from the domain.) If the computer account still exists, delete it.
4. In `sysdm.cpl`, rejoin the domain.
5. Reboot.

Comment: Same thing. I could not rejoin the domain. It is not contacting the DC.

Comment: Run `ipconfig /all`. Note the IP address of your DNS server. Is it set to the IP address of the DC? If not, run `ncpa.cpl` and edit the properties for your active network connection. Be sure that your primary DNS server is a domain controller for the domain that you are trying to join.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, as uSlackR suggests, the issue was origined by the order of the DNS in the adapter, i put the primary DNS the AD instead of second, and i recover the domain "location"

Answer (score 0):

If windows firewall is enable, you need to disable it. Since you already behind a firewall no need for windows firewall on the machine to be enable.

go to control panel disable windows firewall on the pc
then go to command prompt run :gpupdate and :ipconfig /flushdns
and then run :net view all the machine on the domain should be listed

Comment: Windows Firewall would have nothing to do with this as it has default settings to allow domain traffic anyway. Most firewall software already disables the built-in one on install, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to reinstall peachtree on a windows 10 machine on the domain. Ultimately I just mapped the drive via the name of the server instead of the IP. I also changed the network type to domain via static DNS as pointed out above because it got switched to private. With both of these setup I was able to install without a problem. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue that I couldn't browse my domain users on a Windows 7 Pro, when I set the my network config as my DC (DNS and gateway, because we have two different gateways) all it's fine and now I can browse my domain users inside my Win7 pc.